# No suitable method found when using Comparable and Collection.Sort

Tags: java, junit, comparable, hamcrest

The code is just supposed to compare Box volumes and sort them in ascending order. I'm using Junit to test the code and when I try to run it I get this. Never used stack overflow before so I'm sorry if this is the wrong way to post a question.

[Terminal Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSQPE.png)

- 

```
samin@Samins-MacBook-Air src % javac -cp ".:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:junit-4.12.jar" BoxProcessorTest.java
BoxProcessorTest.java:131: error: no suitable method found for sort(List<Box>)
        Collections.sort(expected);
                   ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: Box
        lower bounds: Comparable<? super T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
BoxProcessorTest.java:203: error: no suitable method found for sort(List<Box>)
        Collections.sort(evenList);
                   ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: Box
        lower bounds: Comparable<? super T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
2 errors
```

- 

this is the Box Class that implements comparable and the second one is the Class that sorts and finds specific boxes:

````
import java.util.Objects;

```

    /**
     * The Box class models a three-dimensional box
     */
    public class Box implements Comparable<Box>{
        private final int height;
        private final int width;
        private final int depth;
        
    
        /**
         * Create a new Box with the specified dimensions (height, width, depth).
         *
         * @param height the height of the box
         * @param width the width of the box
         * @param depth the depth of the box
         */
        public Box(int height, int width, int depth) {
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
            this.depth = depth;
        }
    
        /**
         * Create a copy of box.
         *
         * @param box A Box to copy.
         */
        public Box(Box box) {
            this.height = box.height;
            this.width = box.width;
            this.depth = box.depth;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get this box's volume
         *
         * @return the box's volume
         */
        public int volume() {
            return height * width * depth;
        }
    
             @Override
        public int compareTo(Box o){
            int x = ((Integer)this.volume()).compareTo(o.volume());
            return x;
    
        }
    
    //....get height
    //...get width
    //....get depth
````

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BoxProcessor  {




    public void sort(Box[] array){
        for(int i = 0; i<=array.length-1;i++ ){
            int min = 0;
            for(int j = i+1; j<=array.length-1; j++){
                if(array[j].compareTo(array[min]) < 0){
                    min = j;
                    Box temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[min];
                    array[min] = temp;

                }
            }

        }

    }
  
    public void sort(List<Box> list){
       
        for(int i = 0; i<=list.size()-1;i++ ){
            int min = 0;
            for(int j = i+1; j<=list.size()-1; j++){
                if(list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(min)) < 0){
                    min = j;
                    Box temp = list.get(i);
                    list.set(i,list.get(min));
                    list.set(min,temp);
                    

                }
            }

        }

    }

    public int sequentialSearch(Box[] array, Box box){
        for(int i = 0; i<=array.length-1; i++){
            if(array[i].compareTo(box) == 0){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int sequentialSearch(List<Box> list, Box box){
        for(int i = 0; i<=list.size()-1; i++){
            if(list.get(i).compareTo(box) == 0){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int binarySearch(Box[] array, Box box){
        int lowerBound = 0;
        int upperBound = array.length -1;
        while(lowerBound <= upperBound){
            int index = (int)Math.floor((lowerBound-upperBound)/2);
            if(array[index].compareTo(box) == 0){
                return index;
            }
            else if(array[index].compareTo(box) < 0){
                upperBound = index -1;
            }
            else if(array[index].compareTo(box) > 0){
                lowerBound = index +1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int binarySearch(List<Box> list, Box box){
        int lowerBound = 0;
        int upperBound = list.size() -1;
        while(lowerBound <= upperBound){
            int index = (int)Math.floor((lowerBound-upperBound)/2);
            if(list.get(index).compareTo(box) == 0){
                return index;
            }
            else if(list.get(index).compareTo(box)  < 0){
                upperBound = index -1;
            }
            else if(list.get(index).compareTo(box)  > 0){
                lowerBound = index +1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }



}
```

```
I have no idea why I'm getting this error. I've searched for the problem but didn't find any answers
```

Answer (score 0):

T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,**Comparator<? super T#2>**)

BoxProcessorTest.java:203: error: no suitable method found for sort(List)
**Collections.sort(evenList);**

Do you have something implementing Comparator? You need to change it to use Comparable instead